# Understanding zip functions

Tags: python, for-loop, sum

I am new to learning python, I have been using source material for inspiration on how to code an alarm clock. I was wondering if anyone could explain a couple of the lines for me?

```
print("Set a time for the alarm (Ex. 06:30 or 18:30:00)")

while True:

    alarm_input = input(">> ")

    try:

        alarm_time = [int(n) for n in alarm_input.split(":")]

        if check_alarm_input(alarm_time):

            break

        else:

            raise ValueError

    except ValueError:

        print("ERROR: Enter time in HH:MM or HH:MM:SS format")

# Convert the alarm time from [H:M] or [H:M:S] to seconds

seconds_hms = [3600, 60, 1]  # Number of seconds in an Hour, Minute, and Second

alarm_seconds = sum(
    [a*b for a, b in zip(seconds_hms[:len(alarm_time)], alarm_time)])
```

The while True is just referring to the check_alarm_input function I have which makes sure that the input is an actual time.

I am mainly confused by the line converting the alarm time to seconds,

I am not sure what a and b is and what is the purpose of the colon in:

```
zip(seconds_hms[:len(alarm_time)]
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

Comment: And note that the zip goes further: `zip(seconds_hms[:len(alarm_time)], alarm_time)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the user inputs the string `"1:20:45"`.

Then, the `alarm_time` list will be `[1, 20, 45]`.

The `seconds_hms` will of course always be `[3600, 60, 1]`.

Next, let's look at `seconds_hms[:len(alarm_time)]`.

`len(alarm_time)` is `3` in this example, so this is equivalent to `seconds_hms[:3]`.

This is a slicing operation, which slices the `seconds_hms` list from index `0` implicitly, and slices up to (but not including) index `3`, which would be the fourth item, and then returns the new sliced list. In this case, the sliced list is the same as the unsliced list `[3600, 60, 1]`. If the user had entered the string `"1:20"`, then `len(alarm_time)` would be `2`, which means the slice would be from `0` to `2` (not including index `2`), which means the sliced list would be `[3600, 60]`.

Going back to my original example, what we have now is equivalent to `zip([3600, 60, 1], [1, 20, 45])`. `zip` will yield tuples that contain the next item from each iterable. So, the first tuple will be `(3600, 1)`, the second tuple will be `(60, 20)`, and the third tuple will be `(1, 45)`.

These tuples are then unpacked into `a` and `b` in the list-comprehension. So, during the first iteration, `a` will be `3600` and `b` will be `1`. During the second iteration, `a` will be `60` and `b` will be `20`. In the third iteration `a` will be `1` and `b` will be `45`.

Essentially, the list comprehension is constructing a list that looks like: `[3600 * 1, 60 * 20, 1 * 45]`.

Which is equivalent to: `[3600, 1200, 45]`.

You then take the sum of that list to get `4845` seconds.

If the user had entered `1:20` instead of `1:20:45`, like I mentioned earlier, then `len(alarm_time)` would be `2` instead of `3`. This means the sliced list we pass to `zip` would be shorter:

`zip([3600, 60], [1, 20])`

Which means `zip` would only yield two tuples, which means our list-comprehension would only have two iterations, and the constructed list would only have two values:

`[3600 * 1, 60 * 20]`.

That being said, the slicing operationg is not required, since `zip` will stop yielding tuples as soon as one of its iterables is exhausted. That means you can simply write: `zip(seconds_hms, alarm_time)`, and your script should behave exactly the same way.

Comment: Thank you for taking the out for this answer, it has helped a lot